# Edit existing pdf file using evopdf

Tags: c#, file-io, evopdf

Is it possible to edit an existing pdf file using evopdf coverter? I am successfully able to generate a pdf out of html content. However, I am not able to edit existing one. Any suggestions please?

I am using ASP.Net with C#.Net 4.0

Comment: Hi Anil, what do you mean by 'edit an existing pdf'. There are some tools out there which will allow you to convert a pdf in to a HTML or RTF file which would then allow you to edit these other file types.

Comment: @Mark - I mean to use existing pdf as a template and then replace the placeholders in the template at run-time and return the modified file as pdf to user.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Anil. Sounds interesting. Not sure that evopdf can do that as haven't tried that approach but sounds a good one if you can get it to work. Good luck.